# Google Script to Match A Cell Between Two Sheets and Update A Cell In Second Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

In sheet1 I have data that is updated in cell A2 and cell B2.  When they are updated I want to run a script that matches the value in A2 with column Q in a different worksheet and when it finds the match, updates the relevant row in column R with the data in cell B2 from sheet1.  All variations I have found look to move entire rows or haven't worked.  I am a beginner with Script as I have used VBA for years and there only appears to be vague similarities.

Comment: Column Q and R are in a different sheet in the same spreadsheet or a different spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi, A different spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function onSheetEdit(e)
{
  // get the source range that was edited
  var sourceRange = e.range;

  // get the associated sheet
  var sourceSheet = sourceRange.getSheet();

  // get the sheet name
  var sourceSheetName = sourceSheet.getName();

  if(sourceSheetName == "Sheet1")
  {
    // if the range edited was one we carea bout
    if(sourceRange.getA1Notation() == "A2" || sourceRange.getA1Notation() == "B2")
    {

      // get the values
      var values = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:B2").getDisplayValues()[0];

      // open the destination sheet
      var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ldtZdDiml01_Drlp2WvZ3CaSgABoubauok3BcVq11eI").getSheetByName("Sheet1");

      // find the column number of the column we're going to look against
      var searchColumnNumber = destinationSheet.getRange("Q1").getColumn();

      // get all of the values for the column
      var destinationSheetColumnRValues = destinationSheet.getSheetValues(1, searchColumnNumber, -1, 1);

      // find the row that has the value we want
      var foundRow = destinationSheetColumnRValues.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, index) {
        if(currentValue[0] == values[0] && accumulator == -1) return index;
        return accumulator;
      }, -1);

      // if we found it
      if(foundRow != -1)
      {
        // set the value in the destination sheet
        destinationSheet.getRange("R" + (foundRow + 1 )).setValue(values[1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll need to set this function as the `on edit` trigger on the sheet. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events for more details.

This code is could be made more efficient depending on the situation. For example, if the destination column is always sorted, or the column being searched against is never changed, etc...

Comment: Worked perfectly and the explanations were invaluable to a beginner. Much appreciated.